# How can I find a specific folder, multiple times, in a directory?

Tags: python

I am working with a directory with multiple similarly structured folders. I want to find a folder, multiple times, in this directory. Fiddle with files inside of it. then continue on the os.walk() until that folder is found again, repeating the process.

example:

```
directory:
    ----X3
        ----Tim
        ----Jan
        ----Eric
    ----X4
        ----Tim
        ----Jan
        ----Eric
```

I want to find both instances of the "Tim" folder, and perform similar actions inside of it.

as a side note, it would also be very helpful if I can also get the name of the folder above it as well. so files inside the "Tim" folder could be named "X3 - Tim - ThingIWantToDo.file" and "X4 - Tim - ThingIWantToDo.file"

I know that `os.walk()` can go through a directory in its entirety. and it can very easily find specific files. Finding specific folders is apparently much harder.

```py
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('C:\\'):
    print('The current folder is ' + folderName)

    for subfolder in subfolders:
        print('SUBFOLDER OF ' + folderName + ': ' + subfolder)
    for filename in filenames:
        print('FILE INSIDE ' + folderName + ': '+ filename)
```

This works great for just listing everything. but what I want is that when the `folderName` path includes the filename I am looking for, my `thingIWantToDO()` code will execute and it will then continue on.

something like this

```py
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('C:\\'):
        if folderName contains 'Tim':
            andFolderContainingTim = folderName[:-10] #or some number.
            thingIWantToDO(folderName, andFolderContainingTim)
```

I want to save two things from this os.walk(),
* first, the folder just above the specific searched for folder. (the X3 to the Tim)
* second, get the folder path so that the rest of my code can continue working.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pathlib`:

`mkdir A A/1 A/2 A/3 B B/1 B/3 B/4`

```
.
├── A
│   ├── 1
│   ├── 2
│   └── 3
└── B
    ├── 1
    ├── 3
    └── 4
```

```
from pathlib import Path

def find_all(name):
    return list(p for p in Path().glob("**/"+name) if p.is_dir() )

find_all("1")
>>>[PosixPath('A/1'), PosixPath('B/1')]
```

Note that the returned list is made of [`Path` instances](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) but you could just wrap the `p` in `str(p)` to just get the names.

From these `Path` instances it's easy to get the parent directory:

```
dirs = find_all("1")
parent_directories = [p.parent for p in dirs]
>>> [PosixPath('A'), PosixPath('B')]
```

Comment: This is good. I can use the str version of that find_all to get a file path for my purposes.

the parent, and parents[] are also good for getting the path instances, however I am unsure as to how I can get just the parent folder name, as a string. I would imagine it would have something to do with p.parent - p.parents[1]

edit: scratch that, it is `p.parent.stem`!